# Python 2.7 : Kill last background process

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, background-process

I'm using `subprocess.call(ping ... &, shell=True)` to run a background process, and after 5 secondes, I want to kill this process. I'm trying with the Bash equivalent `kill $!` but it's not working.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried like this, try with `subprocess.Popen` :

```
import os
import signal
import time
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("ssh root@192.168.180.11 'echo 'rootpass' | sudo -Sv && bash -s' < ../attaques/Ping_flood.sh &", shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: It's returning  `NameError : name 'process' is not defined`

Comment: can you give your full syntax, like how you are open subprocess

Comment: Oh figured it out. Forgot to use process. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well now : `AttributeError : 'int' object has no attribute 'pid'`
This is the command :
`process = subprocess.call("ssh root@192.168.180.11 'echo 'rootpass' | sudo -Sv && bash -s' < ../attaques/Ping_flood.sh &", shell=True)`

Comment: I think instead of `subprocess.call` try with `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: Well this time:
`os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM`
`OSError : [Errno 3] No such process`

Comment: @JoeJoe are you sure you have file like `../attaques/Ping_flood.sh` ?

Comment: Yes and it's executed. I've found an other way, basically just to specify -w to ping in order to make it last 5 seconds. But I'm still interested in knowing why it's not working with Popen

Comment: I think the file path you've given may not understandable to Popen.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try to do something as soon as possible!

Comment: its glad to help you dude :)